# IF formula with OR statement not working as expected - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript

I have a script that retrieves four values.
For the sake of simplicity I've replaced them with actual numbers here.

It then decides which function to proceed with based on an if statement:

```
function myFunction() {

    var firstvar = 1000;
    var secondvar = (100 - firstvar);
    var thirdvar = 1000;
    var fourthvar = (100 - thirdvar);

    if (secondvar < 0 || fourthvar < 0) {

        first function here

    } else {

        second function here

    }
};
```

I only want the first function to perform if either secondvar or fourthvar are negative numbers, else I want the second function to perform.

EDIT: The above script is now working as expected. I had been confused between using and (&&) and or (||).

Comment: you want first function to run if secondvar and fourthvar are `both` negative, but your using `or` which is ||, you should be using `and` which is &&

Comment: then it should be secondvar >= 0 && fourthvar >= 0 to check if both of them are positive

Comment: What is not working? Can you compare given result against desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is not working? Works fine.

```js
function myFunction() {

    var firstvar = 1000;
    var secondvar = (100-firstvar);
    var thirdvar = 1000;
    var fourthvar = (100-thirdvar);

    if (secondvar < 0 || fourthvar < 0) {

        console.log('yep');

    } else {

        console.log('nope');

    }
};

myFunction();
```

Comment: This is the same as his question.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {

  var firstvar = 1000;
  var secondvar = (100 - firstvar);
  var thirdvar = 1000;
  var fourthvar = (100 - thirdvar);

  if (secondvar < 0 && fourthvar < 0) {

    firtFunction()

  } else {

    secondFunction()

  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need and "and", not an "or":

`if (secondvar < 0 && fourthvar < 0) {`

Comment: Apologies, I must have corrected this after you responded, I meant to say if either are negative. The math just doesn't appear to be working as expected and I was entering if I was doing something wrong!

Comment: Ah, OK. In that case I don't know, maybe add brackets around the two conditions and try to see what each expression evaluates to?

Answer (score 0):

Your function looks right to me, maybe there is some issue in the code that we are not seeing here, please show the error or the issue you are facing when running the script

If i run the below ocde in my broswer, it alerts Yep
The issue is with some other code which we are not seeing here

```
<script>
unction myFunction() {
var firstvar = 1000;
var secondvar = (100-firstvar);
var thirdvar = 1000;
var fourthvar = (100-thirdvar);
if (secondvar < 0 || fourthvar < 0) {
alert('yep');
 } else {
    alert('nope');
}
};
 myFunction();
 </script>
```